# Central limit theorem for Bernoulli$(1/k)$ random variables ($k\in\mathbb{N}$)

Tags: limits, probability-theory, generating-functions, central-limit-theorem

Consider a sequence $(X_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of independent Bernoulli$(1/k)$ random variables.

Then, as $n\rightarrow\infty$,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n1/k\sim\log(n)$$
and
$$
\text{Var}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n(1/k-1/k^2)\sim\log(n).$$
**Question:** Is it true that
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nX_k-\log(n)}{\sqrt{\log(n)}}
$$
converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable?

**Attempted answer:**

The generating function of
$$
Y_n:=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nX_k-\log(n)}{\sqrt{\log(n)}}
$$
is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[z^{Y_n}\right]=z^{-\sqrt{\log(n)}}\prod_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[\left(z^{1/\sqrt{\log(n)}}\right)^{X_k}\right].
$$
But
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(z^{1/\sqrt{\log(n)}}\right)^{X_k}\right]=\left(z^{1/\sqrt{\log(n)}}+1-k\right)/k...
$$
I'm not sure how to progress. Perhaps there is some taylor expansion argument which I am not seeing. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Alternatively, have you checked out Lindberg CLT?

Comment: Thanks, that does it!

Comment: @user301395 Good! Maybe you could post your solution as answer.